# Find all pending transactions from my account with web3

Tags: web3js, parity

I've sent a few transactions a few days ago and they haven't been mined yet. Now I try to find them because they do not show up on etherscan at all. I tried finding my transactions with various web3 functions but didn't have any success so far. Then I stumbled accross parity_pendingTransactions and txpool_content to see If my transactions are still there. Unfortunately I don't have a node set up on my PC right now. Parity is still syncing and I think this will go on for a bit. Is there a way to get a list of all pending transactions with web3? Or is there a way to get something like txpool_content or parity_pendingTransactions using metamask?

Comment: I am needing something similar, did you found a solution?

Comment: you need to install parity and run curl --data '{"method":"parity_pendingTransactions","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX (insert your parity ip here) -o log.txt
this will create a log.txt with all pending transactions

Comment: thanks!, I am running that command (using my parity info), but I am getting this error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid request"},"id":1}. What is the id parameter?

Comment: I found the issue, it was a hidden character, thanks!

Comment: I am trying to get the value from of each pending transaction on log.txt but I do not see that field, do you know how to get it?