# Web3 Unconfirmed Balance

Tags: web3js, ether, balances, pending-transactions

Is there a way to get unconfirmed balance from an address?

I read this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25911/how-can-i-get-eth-balance-with-pending-transaction)

It uses a method filter, not available on present web3 version. After doing some research I found a method `w3.eth.getPastLogs`.Which according to [documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=getpastlogs#getpastlogs) it was the method called behind the scenes by a previous method `pendingTransactions` (not available anymore).

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @de_ninja who had a similar need on this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32964/find-all-pending-transactions-from-my-account-with-web3)

If we use parity we can do:

```
curl --data '{
    "method":"parity_pendingTransactions",
    "params":[],
    "id":1,
    "jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X 
  POST 34.194.17.216:8545 -o log.txt
```

With this we will save on log.txt all pending transactions in json format. From this file we can parse it and filter if a specific address have a pending transaction.